# How to use "window.parent.document" between iframes with different domains

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe, cross-domain

I have the JSP "A" and JSP "B", and the JSP "B" is configured as iframe into the JSP "A", but both are in different domains.  When I try to access an element by id contained in the JSP "A" using jQuery `$("#id_parent_element", window.parent.document)`, I'm denied permission. There is some solution to this problem without having to put both pages in the same domain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First link on google "cross domain iframes" yields http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: It's the 2nd link on different domain iframes.. but still are we really down voting on how Google'able stuff is?

Comment: @ShaneC I am. If it's a "tell me" without proper code or other reasons presented why it was hard to find the info. Also using "Thanks in advance" for a dead simple question to google with a user of rep 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-domain interaction is heavily controlled in browsers. But, some hacks exist. Check this out: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

[No, there isn't.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)